# How do I test endpoints registered with Wagtail Hooks?

Tags: python, hook, wagtail

#### Background

OK, I have a library [wagtail_references](https://github.com/thclark/wagtail_references) which, like many snippet libraries, uses [wagtail hooks](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.5/reference/hooks.html) to add admin views into the wagtail CMS.

Say I have, in my `wagtail_hooks.py`

```py
@hooks.register('register_admin_urls')
def register_admin_urls():
    return [
        url(r'^references/', include(admin_urls, namespace='wagtailreferences')),
    ]
```

And the views that get registered are in `views/reference.py`:

```py
@permission_checker.require('add')
def add(request):
    Reference = get_reference_model()
    ReferenceForm = get_reference_form(Reference)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        # STUFF I WANT TO TEST BECAUSE IT DOESN'T WORK PROPERLY
    else:
        form = ReferenceForm(user=request.user)

    return render(request, "wagtail_references/references/add.html", {'form': form})
```

So in my `test_stuff.py` file, I'd have:

```py
class TestReferenceIndexView(TestCase, WagtailTestUtils):

    def setUp(self):
        self.login()

    def post(self, params=None):
        params = params if params else {}
        return self.client.post(reverse('wagtailreferences:add'), params)

    def test_simple(self):
        response = self.post()
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 201)
```

#### The Problem

But `test_simple` fails, because of course the urls for the view its testing are hooked in dynamically, not defined in `urls.py`. I get:

```
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: 'wagtailreferences' is not a registered namespace
```

#### The question

How can I test endpoints whose URLs are registered by wagtail hooks?

#### I've tried

Registering the hooks manually in the test case, like:

```
class TestReferenceIndexView(TestCase, WagtailTestUtils):
    def setUp(self):
        self.register_hook('register_admin_urls', register_admin_urls)
```

Comment: Can't see anything wrong here - Wagtail's own sub-apps (images, documents etc) routinely use `register_admin_urls` and use the same pattern for tests. Have you added your app to your test environment's `INSTALLED_APPS` setting?

Comment: thanks for your time, @gasman, problem was *ahem* "Human"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DOH! I hadn't registered the admin urls in my test app.

`tests/urls.py` looked like this:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from wagtail.core import urls as wagtail_urls
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'', include(wagtail_urls)),
]
```

But now looks like this:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from wagtail.admin import urls as wagtailadmin_urls
from wagtail.core import urls as wagtail_urls
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(wagtailadmin_urls)),
    url(r'', include(wagtail_urls)),
]
```

Fixed. Sigh.